# Comparing the Tables of one Database to another

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two different databases that share some of the same tables, and differ by a few tables. Is there a way that I can get an output of the differences between just the table names in the databases?

I'm using MS SQL Server, and both of the tables are on the same DB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a database compare tool like [DBComparer](http://dbcomparer.com/)
 Its absolutely free as well and works great for me.

Answer (score 2):

You just want to know the difference in table names? You can outer join onto `sys.tables` for this.

```
;WITH A
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   msdb.sys.tables
         WHERE  type = 'U'),
     B
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   master.sys.tables
         WHERE  type = 'U')
SELECT COALESCE(A.name, B.name) AS Name,
       CASE
         WHEN A.name IS NULL THEN 'A'
         ELSE 'B'
       END                      AS DB
FROM   A
       FULL OUTER JOIN B
         ON A.name = B.name
WHERE  ( B.name IS NULL
          OR A.name IS NULL )
ORDER  BY DB,
          Name
```

Comment: Where do you specify the 2 databases to compare?

Comment: In this example I am comparing the tables in `msdb` and `master`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you feel about using a third party DB utility but Toad for SQL Server (made by dell) works great for side by side comparisons.

http://software.dell.com/landing/218/?gclid=CjwKEAjwyqOwBRDZuIO4p5SV8w0SJAAQoUSwC6B8BfgAQLML_8o3j9Bw1sUL01EljAjF9eXlZrY-nxoCYsjw_wcB